# Can't login to wp-admin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can't login to wp-admin in wordpress because of the following code in user.php. It gets htttp 500 error. How can I solve this.

```
$user = wp_signon( '', $secure_cookie );
```

Comment: Try disable all your plugins (by rename the `plugin` folder to `plugins-old`) and try again.

Comment: @AlexVand  It is not working. Same error. wp-admin redirect to wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Ftvslanka.lk%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: And your htaccess ? What is there in it ?

Comment: @AlexVand Here is the htaccess code                                                               # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress